# how to get current view name (pagename) in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have a route like this `http://localhost:8000/admin/edit-profile/13`
My pagename is edit-profile.blade.php
and i want to get only `edit-profile`in my view from this route.
any ideas how to accomplish this task ??
any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Request::segment()` to get any segment of `url()` like:

```
{{ Request::segment(1) }}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Controller**

```
public function editProfile($id){
 $rsltTest = yourModelName::find($id);
 return view('edit-profile',compact('rsltTest'));

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('edit-profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@editProfile')->name('edit-profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass the reference like this one, but still you need the id in the url either before edit or after edit depends upon your route -

public function editProfile(ModelClass $id){ //$id holds all the data as per the id
 $data = $id;
 return view('edit-profile',compact('data'));

}
```